# getting error on ant command in windows 10

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, ant

I am following this https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html, according to "1.3 Deploy the application to Tomcat" on this link I run ant on cmd and got error(Please see the attached image.).   my environmental variables values are

```
JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\
ANT_HOME  C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.7
PATH   %JAVA_HOME%\bin
       %ANT_HOME%\bin
APACHE LOCATION ON MY SYSTEM IS C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\lib. 

# Ant properties for building the springapp
appserver.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=appserver.home/lib
deploy.path=appserver.home/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH4Xo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is I would suggest to resolve:
 - Open the `springapp/build.properties` file in a text editor of your choice.
 - locate the property `appserver.home` and provide absolute path(use path separator in unix style i.e., '/' even on windows) of the application server as value.
 - Save the file.

Now run the build script / ant target, it should resolve the issue.

Update:

From the comments updating the answer.

Change below line in the property  from:

`appserver.lib = appserver.home/lib`

To:

`appserver.lib = ${appserver.home}/lib`

Comment: # Ant properties for building the springapp

#appserver.home=${user.home}/apache-tomcat-7.0.34
appserver.home=$C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.34
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret

Comment: Remove $ from property value

Comment: Can you please update the question with the properties? Currently it is not clear since you added in the comments area.